# Data file handling modify function error c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
    class flight //main class flight which the user uses to book tickets
{

    int booking_id;
    int pnr,p_age;
    char p_name[25],d_a_name[25],a_a_name[25],gender,departing_date[10],arrival_date[10],b_id;
    long double price;
public:
    flight()
    {
        static int id=0;
        booking_id=id++;
    }

    void modfunction(int n);
};
void flight::modfunction(int n) //function for entering new values when the user has chosen to modify
{
    getchar();
    cout<<"Enter the passenger's name :";
    gets(p_name);
    cout<<"Enter the passenger age :";
    cin>>p_age;
    getchar();
    cout<<"Enter the passenger's gender :";
    cin>>gender;
    getchar();
    cout<<"Enter the departing date(dd-mm-yyyy) :";
    gets(departing_date);
    cout<<"Do you want to book return ticket with a 10% discount?(y/n) :";
    cin>>return_ticket_input;
    if(return_ticket_input=='y')
    {
        cout<<"Enter the arrival date :";
        gets(arrival_date);
    }
    cout<<"Choose the airline.\n\n";
    flights(departing_date,return_ticket_input,arrival_date);
    cout<<"\n\nEnter the desired flight number :";
    cin>>selected_fno;

}
void modify_ticket()//function for modifying a ticket
{
    int n;
    system("clear");
    cout<<"Enter the booking id for modification ";
    cin>>n;
    flight f;
    fstream fp("flight.dat",ios::binary);
    ifstream ifile("flight.dat",ios::binary);
    int found=0;
    int count_variable = 0;
    while(ifile.read((char*)&f,sizeof(f)))
    {
        if(n==f.retbid())
        {
            f.output();
            f.modfunction(n);
//            int s=sizeof(f) * (count_variable + 1);
            fp.seekp(ifile.tellg());
            fp.write((char*)&f,sizeof(f));
            found = 1;
            f.output();
            getchar();
        }
        count_variable++;
    }
    ifile.close();
    fp.close();

    if(found==0)
    {
        cout<<"Passenger not founed!";

    }
    cout<<"Press any key to continue.";
    getch();

}
```

So this is the minimal version of my problem.
The class named flight. a function called *modfuction* which is used to input data from the user. and another function called modify ticket used by the user to modify the record details.

The problem is even though the user enters the booking id(n) and it outputs the record, when the user tries to update it(modify) it stays the same!

please help me as this is a part of my school project!

thanks in advance!

Comment: There is not enough information here. There is barely even a question.

Comment: Please, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I did the best I could!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fstream fp("flight.dat",ios::binary);` write:

```
fstream fp("flight.dat",ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
```

P.S.: Encountered Same Problem A minute ago..